# Apache and selinux, use of linux command in retrieving files

Tags: linux, apache, selinux

how can we access an Apache server using a Linux command, to retrieve file.
the file which is to be retrieved has been copied to  a directory.

Comment: One very good command-line tool to access a web page is [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you are doing, I would suggest looking into `wget` or `curl`.

For example: to copy a file available on a web server via url to the current directory using the wget command:

```
wget http://www.example.com/path/to/file.txt
```

or, if you are accessing your web server by IP address:

```
wget http://192.168.1.1/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: initially i copied a file to a web serving directory using a shell script.

Comment: now i want to retrieve that file using a Linux command. suppose file1 copied to dir1 using script bash1. please provide the syntax and expression using this example - if you could

Comment: I added an example of how to download a file using `wget`.  In a linux environment you can usually get information on command usage via the `man` command, e.g. `man wget`.